# Rail 3, Paperclip Custom Interpolations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using [this upload file example](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example).

And I am trying to modify a :url of the attached file.It does not work somehow.I get this error in the terminal:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `upload_file_size' for #<Paperclip::Attachment:0x8ca35e8>):
```

My upload.rb:

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :upload, :upload_file_name, :upload_file_size

Paperclip::interpolates :upload_file_size do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.upload_file_size
end
  has_attached_file :upload,

                    :url =>"/system/Files/CEL-Files/:upload_file_size/:basename.:extension",
                    :path =>":rails_root/public/system/Files/CEL-Files/:piks/:basename.:extension"

  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

And this is my schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20120731045929) do

  create_table "uploads", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "upload_file_name"
    t.string   "upload_content_type"
    t.string   "user"
    t.integer  "upload_file_size"
    t.datetime "upload_updated_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",          :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",          :null => false
  end

end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: may be it is conflicting with your model attribute "upload_file_size". Try changing paperclip interpolation custom name from "upload_file_size" to something else.

Comment: Do zou mean something like this Paperclip::interpolates :piks do...? If yes, then it creates the folder named :piks and same all the files there. So it does not create a folder named after the size of a file. It seems that it does not interpolate at all now

Comment: No. It will create the folder with file size as you are returning `attachment.instance.upload_file_size` from that interpolation. Have you tried this ?

Comment: oh. It worked now. Yep. Thanks you a lot. Would you like to post it as a normal answer, so I can vote it?

Comment: I have posted it as an answer.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol/string you are using in Paperclip interpolation is conflicting with your model attribute "upload_file_size". Try changing Paperclip interpolation custom name from "upload_file_size" to something else. Like below :

```
Paperclip::interpolates :size_of_file do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.upload_file_size
end
```